# Putting williams pivot high/lows into an array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How would i store williams pivot high and low values into an array? Example: when a new pivot low is formed, it puts that low value into the array

Here's what i have

```
//Float arrays
var float[] _lowLiqValues  = array.new_float()
var float[] _highLiqValues  = array.new_float()



//Williams Fractal Period
n = input.int(defval =3, title ="Fractal Period")

//Defining Pivots with n period
pivotHigh = ta.pivothigh(high, n, n)
pivotLow = ta.pivotlow(low,n,n)


//If pivot, put low value or high value to float array
if pivotHigh
    highPVT = high[n]
    array.push(_highLiqValues, highPVT)

if pivotLow 
    lowPVT = low[n]
    array.push(_lowLiqValues, lowPVT)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ta.pivothigh()` and `ta.pivotlow()` return the pivot price. So, you can directly push their return values.

```
if (not na(pivotHigh))
    array.push(_highLiqValues, pivotHigh)

if (not na(pivotLow))
    array.push(_lowLiqValues, pivotLow)
```